# RSelenim Cannot define class using reflection

Tags: r, web-scraping

I came accross this error a few days ago, trying many ways with no solution. I have already install Selenium, but in R something wrong:

```
remDr $ open ()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:Cannot define class using reflection

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
> remDr $ navigate ( "https://www.google.com.tw/" )
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

[image]

It really puzzled me, I thought of the version disorder, but changing version of selenium or chromedriver didn't work. How to solve it?